# What is the adequate terminology for describing a page/view representing a business concept?

Tags: information-architecture, information-design

In the context of information systems, and in particular during information design, what is the adequate terminology for referring to the views of the business concepts?

E.g., considering the StackExchange system, what is the correct name for the pages about a *question*, *topic*, *user*, etc. Basically, the most important 'information concepts' of the domain. I view these as the core elements of the information architecture project.

Possible names: 'information unit', 'information object', 'view', 'main page', 'anchor page', simply 'page'.

What is the adequate term in the field?

Answer (score 1):

"Topic page", "User page", "Questions main page" would be adequate in a site map. Use "page" with a descriptive label.

You could use "tab" or "view" for elements within a page if you need to clarify that those are important. E.g. "Users page, recent users view."

Comment: Thanks for your input. Maybe I wasn't clear but I am looking for a term to refer to all those pages. Should I call them just 'pages'? But I would like to distinguish these main 'information units' from the 'secondary pages' (e.g. confirmation pages, settings, navigation pages, etc)

Comment: I call them "pages". Sometimes it's helpful to distinguish between front-end pages (that intended audiences see) and back-end pages (that the admins and site-builders see). I would also use "sections" and "modules" for some IA clarification on page groupings, depending on the context. I'd love to hear others' thoughts.

Comment: Yes, 'pages' is what we have been using but that includes all the pages of the system. But I would like to refer to the main (core, anchor) pages of the system. For instance, StackExchange has a lot of individual pages, but the 'anchors' are the 'question pages' and the 'user pages'.

Comment: I can add a little more context. We are in the process of designing a new application and we want to start by designing those 'anchor pages', the rest of the pages will follow. I am searching for the key concepts in UX \ IA to look for examples and information on this task.

Comment: I'd call those sections. The news section, the events section, etc. The top pages of those would be the News main page, the Events main page. On a mobile app, it might be easier to call it a screen vs. a page (home screen, news screen, events screen.) If there is better terminology, I'd like to hear about it, too!

Comment: I think that 'sections' seem like a good way to group UI screens and areas, but I would like to find the term for the 'information design' phase, even before we have screens.

Answer (score 0):

I and the businesses I've worked with would typically and generally refer to these as Detail Screens or Detail Views. Commonly used on mobile as gory details are often reserved for a single screen that can be drilled-down to via lists, dashboards, etc. List items might have a little detail, like a preview, but not the full detail, but the Detail Screen has all the detail.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That seems like a good label from the application point of view, but I am searching for a good concept from an 'information architecture' point of view. While mapping the information space I would like to refer to those 'main information concepts'.

Comment: Well, those are the details pertinent to the domain that you want Users to be able to consume. Instructions shouldn't really be labelled as a 'concept' yet details can exist regarding a concept or instructions.